# Open a file of Type file in python

Tags: python

I have few `mail files` stored without any extension:

[image: mail files]

how to open them??

Comment: i don't get it, you know how to read a file but have no idea how to open it ;)?

Comment: Open like any other file: 
    `target_file = open(final_file_name, "rt")  
    target_file.close()`

Comment: @mic4ael i meant to say that if i can open the file then inside of that file i will be having the whole mail content. The mail content i know how to work with but i don't know how to open the file.

Comment: Please define "open"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open('1', 'r') as fp:
    content = fp.read()
```

This way, the file will always be closed.

Answer (score 3):

To add on to @math2001's answer, you could do something like this:

```
numOfFiles = #int
data = []

for files in range(1, numOfFiles+1):
    with open(str(files), 'r') as f:
        // do whatever data processing you need to do
        fileData = f.read()
        data.append(fileData)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:

```
import os
import glob
files = filter(os.path.isfile, glob.glob("./[0-9]*"))
for name in files:
    with open(name) as fh:
        contents = fh.read()
        # do something with contents (parse email format)
```